# GWT - flextable - adding focus listenter

Tags: gwt, flextable

I'm working on a editable flextable. When a cell is clicked, it turns into  a textbox within that particular cell. The textbox contains the text of the original cell clicked.  Since the "addFocustListener" function is deprecated, which functions should I use to copy the new text typed into the textbox into the flextable.

Following is my code:

```
package testproject3.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ChangeEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ChangeHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.FocusEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.FocusHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Command;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DeferredCommand;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FocusListenerAdapter;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class ViewAndEditCompWidget 
{
    VerticalPanel vPanel=null;
    FlexTable table =null;



    public VerticalPanel getvPanel() 
    {
        table = new FlexTable();
        vPanel = new VerticalPanel();

        table.setText(0, 0, " Name");
        table.setText(0, 1, " Address aasdfasfasfdasfasfdasfasdfasfasdfasfsafasdfsadfsdfasfsdfasdfsafasdfasdfasdf");        

        table.setText(1, 0, " My Name");
        table.setText(1, 1, " 123456789  asfasdfasfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");

        makeTableEditable();
        vPanel.add(table);
        return vPanel;
    }
    public void makeTableEditable()
    {
        table.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) 
            {
                final int cellIndex = table.getCellForEvent(event).getCellIndex();
                final int rowIndex =    table.getCellForEvent(event).getRowIndex();

                //Cell cell = myTable.getCellForEvent(event);
                //int receiverRowIndex = cell.getRowIndex(); 

                //make sure that it is not the header row
                if(rowIndex != 0)
                {
                    //make a new Textbox
                    final TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                    textBox.setText(table.getText(rowIndex, cellIndex));
                    table.setWidget(rowIndex, cellIndex, textBox);

                    /*********************************************
                    DeferredComman is deprecated
                    *********************************************/
                    DeferredCommand.addCommand(new Command()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void execute() 
                        {
                            textBox.setFocus(true);
                            textBox.selectAll();

                        }

                    }
                    );

                    /*********************************************
                    addFocusListener is also deprecated
                    *********************************************/
                    textBox.addFocusListener(new FocusListenerAdapter()
                    {
                        public void onLostFocus(Widget sender)
                        {
                            table.setText(rowIndex, cellIndex, textBox.getText());
                        }
                    }
                    );

                    //add a keyboard listener to the text box
                    //so that it reacts to enter and ESC key
                    textBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) 
                        {
                            //if key pressed was ENTER, copy the text box's text into the table
                            if (event.getCharCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) 
                            {
                                table.setText(rowIndex, cellIndex, table.getText(rowIndex, cellIndex));
                            }
                            else if (event.getCharCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ESCAPE) 
                            {
                                table.setText(rowIndex, cellIndex, textBox.getText()+"");
                            }
                        }//onKeyPress
                    });//addKeyPressHandler
                }//if
            }

        });

    }

}
```

**DeferredCommand** and **addFocustListener** are deprecated. What can be used in their places?

Following is my new code:

```
public class CellTableExample implements EntryPoint {

  /**
   * A simple data type that represents a contact.
   */
  private static class Contact {
    private final String address;
    private final Date birthday;
    private final String name;

    public Contact(String name, Date birthday, String address) {
      this.name = name;
      this.birthday = birthday;
      this.address = address;
    }
  }

  /**
   * The list of data to display.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  private static final List<Contact> CONTACTS = Arrays.asList(
      new Contact("John", new Date(80, 4, 12), "123 Abc Avenue"), 
      new Contact("Joe", new Date(85, 2, 22), "22 Lance Ln fasfasdfasfdasdfasfasdfasfasdfasfasfasdfasdfasdf"), 
      new Contact("Tom", new Date(85, 3, 22), "33 Lance Lnasdfasfdasdfffffffffffffffffff"), 
      new Contact("Jack", new Date(85, 4, 22), "44 Lance Lnsddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"));

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Create a CellTable.
    final CellTable<Contact> table = new CellTable<Contact>();
    // Display 3 rows in one page
    table.setPageSize(3);

    // Add a text column to show the name.
    TextColumn<Contact> nameColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
      @Override
      public String getValue(Contact object) {
        return object.name;
      }
    };
    table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");

    // Add a date column to show the birthday.
    DateCell dateCell = new DateCell();
    Column<Contact, Date> dateColumn = new Column<Contact, Date>(dateCell) {
      @Override
      public Date getValue(Contact object) {
        return object.birthday;
      }
    };
    table.addColumn(dateColumn, "Birthday");

    // Add a text column to show the address.
    TextColumn<Contact> addressColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
      @Override
      public String getValue(Contact object) {
        return object.address;
      }
    };
    table.addColumn(addressColumn, "Address");

    // Associate an async data provider to the table
    // XXX: Use AsyncCallback in the method onRangeChanged
    // to actaully get the data from the server side
    AsyncDataProvider<Contact> provider = new AsyncDataProvider<Contact>() {
      @Override
      protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<Contact> display) {
        int start = display.getVisibleRange().getStart();
        int end = start + display.getVisibleRange().getLength();
        end = end >= CONTACTS.size() ? CONTACTS.size() : end;
        List<Contact> sub = CONTACTS.subList(start, end);
        updateRowData(start, sub);
      }
    };
    provider.addDataDisplay(table);
    provider.updateRowCount(CONTACTS.size(), true);

    SimplePager pager = new SimplePager();
    pager.setDisplay(table);

    VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
    vp.add(table);
    vp.add(pager);

    // Add it to the root panel.
    RootPanel.get().add(vp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listeners are deprecated in GWT since 1.6 you will have to use handlers instead. Do you see a addFocusHandler?

From the gwt site - http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/ReleaseNotes_1_6.html

> Event handlers have been added to replace the old event listeners used by Widgets, History, and various other classes.

ps - Also look at http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable, I think that is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is is possible to resize a EditTextCell that's in a celltable?

Comment: if by resize, you mean on browser resize... then yeah. That is possible.

Comment: what do you mean by browser resize? I've included my code above, the EditTextCell areas are fixed and sometimes some cells contains a lot of data, when a cell is clicked, the EditTextCell does not show all the text.

Comment: It fits to the size of the column. You will have to end up moving with your cursor if the test is more than the size of the grid. Pretty sure that can be customized though. Havent tried that.